# class="thumbnail" how to create a thumbnail of an html page

Tags: javascript, html, thumbnails

i want to create a thumbnail pic like what chrome browser does in representing most visited sites but i have no idea but when i inspect one of them i found class="thumbnail". any idea ;because i have no idea about it are they using scripts or it is just a css or plug in ! and for that i am sorry i have no code .could you please help me or offer me some examples.
note: the html page could include video pictures text map..etc

Comment: thank you David. any another idea

Comment: is there another way rather than using  webkit2png which means i have to code a severer side which i am a ware of the cost of sending and receiving request from the server in other words time and cost . is the an alternative which does the same function but using javascript

Answer (score 1):

Chrome uses a background (although it should be foreground as it is content) image (which is generated internally by the browser).

You'll need to use something like [webkit2png](http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/) (running on your server) if you want to generate an image.

Comment: thank you sire for your response . i need further explanation such as can i generate thumbnail dynamically through  webkit2png and javascript. if you can provide an example this will be nice . any way thank you again

Comment: i want to include a functionality in my website which is making a thumbnail for an html page any idea

Comment: Call it from your server side language of choice for each URI you want to present a thumbnail for, cache the results, then load it like any other image.

Comment: can't  i do it in client side using script as i said . if not i will follow your advice and trying to do it through the server side :) tank you David.

Comment: No you can't. You need something server side.

Comment: is there another way rather than using  webkit2png which means i have to code a severer side which i am a ware of the cost of sending and receiving request from the server in other words time and cost . is the an alternative which does the same function but using javascript.

Comment: In my answer I said "You'll need … on your server". In my previous comment I said "No you can't. You need something server side". That hasn't changed. I also said, in an earlier comment, "cache the results" (which will mitigate the time and cost).